# SignalR performance: Group broadcast Vs looping connections

Tags: performance, signalr, broadcast

From what I've been reading on SignalR, it is better(from performance perspective) to:

```
Clients.Group("GroupA").sendMsg("some message");
```

than to:

```
foreach (var connId in connectionsIds)//assuming I've got a collection of all group A's connection Ids 
{
    Clients.Client(connId).sendMsg("some message")
}
```

Assuming of course you've got a bunch of users inside that group...
Some explanations I saw about the performance boost of using groups, contained phrases I don't understand like the "pub sub model", "message bus", etc...

So my question is: How does the **pub sub model** & **message bus** works internally that makes it to boost the performance? what kind of magic is there? :)

Comment: If you need more logic than what groups give you there is no way around using "connection looping". For example my code here https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/blob/master/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/EventAggregation/EventProxy.cs#L91

Comment: Groups is fine by me, I just want to understand why it is more efficient to use it instead simple looping

Comment: This question was reposted (with answers) here: https://forums.asp.net/t/2084983.aspx